# Optimal way of iterating through a list of lists to maximise unique outputs

Tags: algorithm, r, list, optimization, graph-theory

I have got a list of lists where the content is a vector of characters.  For example:

```
yoda <- list(a=list(c("A","B","C"), c("B","C","D")), b=list(c("D","C"), c("B","C","D","E","F")))
```

This is a much shorter version that what I am actually trying to do it on, for me there is 11 list members each having about 12 sublists.  For each of the list members I need to pick one sub-member liste.g. one list for "a" and one list for "b".  I would like to find which combination of sublists gives the greatest number of unique values, in this simple example it would be the first sublist in "a" and the second sublist in "b" giving a final answer of:

```
c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
```

At the moment I have just got a huge number of nested loops and it seems to be taking for ever.  Here is the poor bit of code:

```
res <- list()
for (a in 1:length(extra.pats[[1]])) {
  for (b in 1:length(extra.pats[[2]])) {
    for (c in 1:length(extra.pats[[3]])) {
      for (d in 1:length(extra.pats[[4]])) {
        for (e in 1:length(extra.pats[[5]])) {
          for (f in 1:length(extra.pats[[6]])) {
            for (g in 1:length(extra.pats[[7]])) {
              for (h in 1:length(extra.pats[[8]])) {
                for (i in 1:length(extra.pats[[9]])) {
                  for (j in 1:length(extra.pats[[10]])) {
                    for (k in 1:length(extra.pats[[11]])) {
                      res[[paste(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k, sep="_")]] <- unique(extra.pats[[1]][[a]], extra.pats[[2]][[b]], extra.pats[[3]][[c]], extra.pats[[4]][[d]], extra.pats[[5]][[e]], extra.pats[[6]][[f]], extra.pats[[7]][[g]], extra.pats[[8]][[h]], extra.pats[[9]][[i]], extra.pats[[10]][[j]], extra.pats[[11]][[k]])
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone has got any ideas how to do this properly that would be great.

Comment: My guess is that, if you do a bit of research, this is a well known problem in graph theory (I would use keywords like "coverage" in searching for it). It might very well be an NP-complete problem. Meaning: either your problem dimension is small enough that you can do an exhaustive search, or you'll have to rely on a suboptimal algorithm leading to "good enough" solutions.

Comment: If you happen to go the "exhaustive search" route, while you might be able to tune this naive for loop approach somewhat, you'll probably eventually want to investigate something like Rcpp.

Comment: How much unique values do you globally have (i.e. how many is `length(unique(unlist(lapply(extra.pats,function(x) unique(unlist(x))))))`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current problem dimensions prohibit an exhaustive search. Here is an example of a suboptimal algorithm. While simple, maybe you'll find that it gives you "good enough" results.

The algorithm goes as follows:

1. Look at your first list: pick the item with the highest number of unique values.
2. Look at the second list: pick the item that brings the highest number of new unique values in addition to what you already selected in step 1.
3. repeat until you have reached the end of your list.

The code:

```
good.cover <- function(top.list) {
    selection <- vector("list", length(top.list))
    num.new.unique <- function(x, y) length(setdiff(y, x))
    for (i in seq_along(top.list)) {
        score <- sapply(top.list[[i]], num.new.unique, x = unlist(selection))
        selection[[i]] <- top.list[[i]][which.max(score)]
    }
    selection
}
```

Let's make up some data:

```
items.universe <- apply(expand.grid(list(LETTERS, 0:9)), 1, paste, collapse = "")
random.length  <- function()sample(3:6, 1)
random.sample  <- function(i)sample(items.universe, random.length())
random.list    <- function(i)lapply(letters[1:12], random.sample)
initial.list   <- lapply(1:11, random.list)
```

Now run it:

```
system.time(final.list <- good.cover(initial.list))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.004   0.000   0.004
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proposal:

```
# create all possible combinations
comb <- expand.grid(yoda)

# find unique values for each combination
uni <- lapply(seq(nrow(comb)), function(x) unique(unlist(comb[x, ])))

# count the unique values
len <- lapply(uni, length)

# extract longest combination  
uni[which.max(len)]

[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

Comment: @flodel This is true. The actual list may be too big for this solution.

Comment: I tried this approach already but the expand.grid couldn't complete due to the size!